# Android carousel image gallery

Tags: android, gallery, carousel

How can i carousel image gallery which never gets end.. after last first image and before first last image.

Comment: This question sounds very familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by creating my own list-adapter (subclassed from 
BaseAdapter). 
I coded my own list-adapter in such a way that its getCount() method 
returns a HUUUUGE number. 
And if item 'x' is selected, then this item corresponds to adapter 
position='adapter.getCount()/2+x' 
And for my adapter's method getItem(int position), i look in my array 
that backs up the adapter and fetch the item on index: 
    (position-getCount()/2) % myDataItems.length 
You need to do some more 'special' stuff to make it all work 
correctly, but you get the idea. 
In principle, it is still possible to reach the end or the beginning 
of the list, but if you set getCount() to around a million or so, this 
is hard to do :-)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you did that as i also want to achieve the same.Thanks