# display the images in single row

Tags: android

Hi i want to display the images one by one that means first i am displaying the some (5) images in a single row.when i am track that view next pair is coming.and when i click on particular image that image will be dispayed as big image in layout which is above of this single row layout.For this which layout are useful that means grid view like that.Give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Comment: This question should be tagged `android`, nothing to do with the manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) View is your best bet. Just google for its examples.

Comment: Thaks for your response but gallary viewis ended but idon't wan't the end .At the end of time i want repeat it again for this what can i do?

Comment: There's no Inbuilt Widget for this...You might look for Android Code For a Image Carousel...It should be easy to implement with an Adapter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854771/android-carousel-image-gallery (Here's a start)