# Change view of Gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

I would to change the view of the gallery. Instead it diplaying images straight across the screen. i would like to make it go in a circle sort of like a carousel.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked before, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854771/android-carousel-image-gallery). It's answer actually seems like a pretty good approach since you won't have to deal with modifying the view itself.

Comment: that is VERY confusing the way he put that. An example is definitely needed there.

Comment: How so? The "hard" part would be implementing your custom Adapter, but you should do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class CircularAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Drawable> mDrawables;

private CircularAdapter(ArrayList<Drawable> drawables){
    mDrawables=drawables;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10000;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Setup custom View
    //...
    imageView.setDrawable(mDrawables.get(position % mDrawables.size()));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Where did you get imageview from in the last line? ImageView doesnt have a method setDrawable.